# Sum of double figures give out a strange number

Tags: c++, double

I'm working with SDL coding a wireframe render.
I need do some operations with double numbers, but the last sum I do gives out very strange numbers.

The snippet of code is:

```
double screenCoordinate[2] = {0, 0};

// now map [-1,1] into the screen coordinates (0,width) and (0,height)
// where (0,0) is the top-left corner of the screen
screenCoordinate[0] = (vertexViewSpace(0) * (640.0/2.0));
screenCoordinate[0] += (640.0/2.0);
screenCoordinate[1] = (-vertexViewSpace(1) * (480.0/2.0));
screenCoordinate[1] += (480.0/2.0);
```

I divided in two parts each operation to more easily debug it.

It doesn't matter what the first value of `screenCoordinate[0]` is, because from the second sum `screenCoordinate[0]` will be equal to the half of `640.0`.

Same for `screenCoordinate[1]`, it doesn't matter the first multiplication value, the last line for the sum make `screenCoordinate[1]` equal to half of `480.0`.

I really don't know why this is happening. Can anyone help me?

P.S.
I've done all the debug you're suggesting.
I'll put her an example I've read during the debug:

```
screenCoordinate[0] = 1.9477670227253643e-017 * 320.0;
screenCoordinate[0] = 6.2328544727211657e-015 + 320.0;
screenCoordinate[1] = -1.2985113484835763e-017 * 240;
screenCoordinate[1] = -3.1164272363605833e-015 + 240.0;
```

So using a calculator the results should be:

```
screenCoordinate[0] = 382,328544727211657;
screenCoordinate[1] = 208,835727636394167;
```

but I get

```
screenCoordinate[0] = 320.00000000000000;
screenCoordinate[0] = 240.00000000000000;
```

Comment: How large are your values for `vertexViewSpace`?

Comment: From what you say is would seem that `vertexViewSpace` returns `0` with both `0` and `1` input. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Maybe you could debug `vertexViewSpace(0)` and `vertexViewSpace(1)`.

Comment: Is it only for me or it sounds like he's saying that after the 2nd operation `screenCoordinate[0]` will be 360.0? (no matter the first operation). Almost like if the code was `screenCoordinate[0] = 360.0` and not `screenCoordinate[0] += 360.0`

Comment: Use constexpr const double instead of [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) And what is the type of return of vertexViewSpace ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the lines where vertexViewSpace is being used and see what their values are after stepping over them.

Comment: This should really be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I've done all the debug you're suggesting. I'll put her an example I've read during the debug:

screenCoordinate[0] = 1.9477670227253643e-017 * 320.0;

screenCoordinate[0] = 6.2328544727211657e-015 + 320.0;

screenCoordinate[1] = -1.2985113484835763e-017 * 240;

screenCoordinate[1] = -3.1164272363605833e-015 + 240.0;


So using a calculator the results should be:

screenCoordinate[0] = 382,328544727211657;

screenCoordinate[1] = 208,835727636394167;


but I get
screenCoordinate[0] = 320.00000000000000;
screenCoordinate[0] = 240.00000000000000;

Comment: I get this same results even with different vertexViewSpace(0) and vertexViewSpace(1), and both are double number, as you can see.
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please put this additional detail in the question, not in a comment, it's barely readable.

Anyway, how are you using the calculator to obtain the expected results?

`1.9477670227253643e-017 * 320.0` and `-1.2985113484835763e-017 * 240` are valued nearly zero, of course they make almost no difference when summed to `320` and `240`.

Comment: But if you look at what I've written the difference is very big! They will be coordinate and, the difference it's huge and this make a mess in my project.
Any ideaa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these calculations:

```
screenCoordinate[0] = 6.2328544727211657e-015 + 320.0;
screenCoordinate[1] = -3.1164272363605833e-015 + 240.0;
```

You say you should get this result:

```
screenCoordinate[0]: 382,328544727211657
screenCoordinate[1]: 208,835727636394167
```

This is however incorrect, you should get this result:

```
screenCoordinate[0]: 320,00000000000000623285447272117
screenCoordinate[1]: 239,99999999999999688357276363942
```

A double is typically represented internally by 8 bytes. With just 8 bytes you cannot represent an infinite set of numbers. You can only represent 2^32 numbers. This causes your results to be rounded to the nearest number you can actually represent with a double, namely:

```
screenCoordinate[0]: 320
screenCoordinate[1]: 240
```

Comment: You're totally right! I was pasting the number in the calculator with a wrong comma, so it was interpreting in a bad way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot precisely add a small number to a large number using doubles. Adding 1.0e-15 to 320.0 will result in 320.0 since you only have finite precision. Try to re-arrange your calculation so that you do not add small and large numbers.